# How to return a view as well as redirect to another action in MVC [or Return a view and reload the current view]?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction, asp.net-mvc-views

I have two actions; First One

```
 public ActionResult ViewRequests()
    {
        List<AgentRequests> Reqs = con.AgentRequests
                                      .Where(x => x.Status == RequestStatus.Open)
                                      .OrderBy(x => x.RequestedOn).ToList();

        return View(Reqs);
    }
```

Second One:

```
 public ActionResult ProcessRequest(long Id)
    {

      // Code to export data to excel file

        //return RedirectToAction("ViewRequests");
        return View(KnoqedUsers);
    }
```

My first action returns a view having a list. Each row of this list is having a link - "Process Request", which when clicked calls the second action.

My second action will produce an excel file output to download.

My problem is - Currently the row which is clicked is processed. So I need to remove it from my view.

If I manually reload the page its OK. But how can I automatically reload it?

I cannot use 2 return statements as shown in my second code. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is fundamentally not how the Internet works. One of the overriding principles of the Internet is what's called request-response. In other words, a request gets one response and a response only follows a request. The client makes a request to a server, and that server returns a response to the client. A view (HTML) is a response and a redirect is *also* a response. Therefore, you cannot possibly return *both*, only one or the other. Likewise, you cannot return an HTML response and then return the HTML response again, without the *client* first replaying the request.